# What is the upward limit on the number of android library modules android studio can support?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recognize this is somewhat like asking how many cells can MS Excel support but I am in the midst of a project where our iOS, Android, Web apps are all breaking things down into many different libraries. On android this has resulted in many different modules. In the near future we may have hundreds of modules. I am wondering if there is an upward limit on when when android studio becomes unusable?

Comment: Hundreds? Tens seems more reasonable for a large-scale project. You've got core Java objects, then WebServices, then perhaps a few Android libraries that can't be added through JCenter, maybe a few test suites, then finally the app itself. Definitely not approaching hundreds.

Comment: Yeah, I understand its not standard. We are adopting atomic design and trying to break down each item into a separate library. Just wondering if any one else out there has worked in a project where they had hundreds of modules or did any one hit a number where it became unmanageable. Keep in mind I am making the argument myself that huge numbers of modules is going to be problematic but I am looking for concrete evidence where it went wrong.

Comment: I doubt there is a limit other than physical hardware. Android Studio will try to index every file of every module in the project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit set on the number of library modules.

However, there is a limit of number of methods of 65k in a single project, which can be reached if you keep on importing a lot of libraries or your codebase becomes too large.

You would then need to use [multidex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)